# Rails cancancan user sees own order, admin can see all users orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan

controller.rb

```
load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /orders or /orders.json
  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      @orders = current_user.orders
    else
      @orders = Order.all
    end
  end
```

ability.rb

```
    if user.user_role?

      can :manage, Order, :user_id => user.id

    end
```

Trying to get normal users to only see their own orders/posts and the admin role users can see all users' posts/orders.

What am I missing? I'm using cancancan and devise.

Comment: did you have `admin` role ? in this case i think you only need to check role

Comment: @LamPhan yup, I have admin role. My normal user can still see all posts/orders instead of just the own user's posts/orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
  def index
    if current_user.superadmin_role?
      @orders = Order.all
    else
      @orders = current_user.orders
    end
  end
```